# How to check which image is on a button's background

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I need to check which image is set as a button background.
There can be three options, which program sets based on several factors.
If the specific background is set after some animation, certain functions should be triggered.

So, i need something like: if(button.getBackgroundImage == certainBackgroundImage){ do something}

Now, I am aware that there is a method to set button background to some image:

```
[button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cloudRed.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

is there a method that will do something like this:

```
UIImage *red cloud = = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cloudRed.png"];
if([cloud imageForState:UIControlStateNormal] == _cloudRed ){

                                 NSLog(@"OMG");
                             }
```

Comment: This is a horrid programming design choice. You shouldn't be using a view that you set to determine which branch of code to run. You should have state get stored in some other way in your model, not check your view to determine your state.

Comment: Yeah, I ended up sorting them by tags, but this method is applicable as well, it's just not that clear from this small code I provided. Thanks for feedback

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [backgroundImageForState method of UIButton returns the UIImage](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIButton/backgroundImageForState%3a)

```
- (UIImage *)backgroundImageForState:(UIControlState)state
```

So pretty much how you described:

```
UIImage *imageToCheckFor = [UIImage imageNamed:@"someImage.png"];

UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button setImage:imageToCheckFor forState:UIControlStateNormal];

// Later to Check

if ([button backgroundImageForState:UIControlStateNormal] == imageToCheckFor) {

}
```